# Which package/module for matching a sample and export the matched sample?

Tags: r, stata, matching

I am looking for recommended procedures/packages for matching samples (with or without propensity scores) to restrict the number of cases in one of two groups. Data are collected with a survey, and a group has substantial dropout (self-selection). I would like to consider this self-selection by using auxiliary variables (covariates) to match individuals from the other group, the group with a high response rate. In case-control studies, this latter group would be referred to as the “control group”.

I believe I cannot integrate the matching in for instance Stata’s -teffects- module since I need to select a restricted/matched sample and then move this sample to advanced analyses with SEM.

Hopefully, someone can give me advice on what would be a good approach. My coding skills are better in R, but I tend to use Stata for data management within a single data frame. So using a package for either Stata or R would be great.

Comment: What kind of matching are you planning on implementing (e.g Nearest Neighbour, Kernel etc)? I suggest you manually program the matching function via the formula for the method, since Stata's psmatch2 will only give you the observation line of the matched observation(s), if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the Matching package in R.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/Matching.pdf

Comment: Why would you start with the matching package in R ? Can you explain why that would be better than, say the matchit package for example ?

Comment: I don't have a strong preference between the matching package and MatchIt.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider Matching and MatchIt (Matching seems to be continuely updated). Stata's -teffects- has matching but seems to be focused on estimating treatment effects. A challenge for me is that I have lots of missing data (not only because of the common non-reponse to single items, but also missing values by design). 

As for the choice between Nearest Neighbour and other methods: I guess I will try alternative solutions and compare the results.  Any further comments/recommendations are welcome.

Comment: You might consider treating missing as a valid value (so code it to a value like -1 if you have fields that are always positive, or filling categorical columns with "Not Answered"). This is valid in a lot of cases-and your case where missing is often by design is one of those cases.

Comment: Thanks, @MelindaThielbar. Do you have a reference for substituting values that are missing by design with a negative number? To me, this seems counter-intuitive and it would be great to learn more.

Comment: I didn't mean to be misleading. Using a set value to stand in for missing on your continuous variables is only valid for the matching portion of the problem, which really isn't a statistical problem. It's a trick I use that generally gives good results, but the effect on the match will depend on your data and your problem.